# Совместимость transform: skew с border и border-radius

Tags: css, transform, border

У меня есть 3 блока со значением transform: skew(0deg, 10deg). При попытке прописать border (см 1 фото) или border-radius (см 2 фото) верхняя (косая) граница становится "ступенчатой".

Без этих свойств "ступенчатости" нет, но мне нужно так стилизовать блоки.

Как можно это пофиксить? Или skew и border априори несовместимы?
[image: border]
[image: border-radius]

Comment: попробуйте тень в 1px того же цвета, что и граница добавить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте в CSS.

```
{ image-rendering: optimizeQuality; 
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```